# Typescript subclass scope issue when calling from parent

Tags: typescript, scope, subclass

I've been pulling my hair with this issue all night so I built a simple (maybe not so simple) example.
The problem is this:

1. I create an abstract class I call `Father`.
2. In the constructor I call an abstract method call `load()`
3. I extend a child class I call `Child`.
4. In that child class I define a property called `_childExtraData` that's not in its father.
5. In the child class I define the method `load()` and attempt to alter `_childExtraData`.

No error is given in all these steps, but the property is not modified, any clues why?

The code I use to test looks like this:

```
abstract class Father<T> {
    protected _fatherData: T = null;
    protected _fatherExtraData: string = null;

    constructor(data: T) {
        this._fatherData = data;

        this.load();
    }

    public fatherData(): T {
        return this._fatherData;
    }
    public fatherExtraData(): string {
        return this._fatherExtraData;
    }

    protected abstract load(): void;
}

class Child extends Father<string> {
    protected _childData: string = null;
    protected _childExtraData: string = null;

    constructor(fatherData: string) {
        super(fatherData);
    }

    public childData(): string {
        return this._childData;
    }
    public childExtraData(): string {
        return this._childExtraData;
    }
    public setChildData(data: string): void {
        this._childData = data;
    }

    protected load(): void {
        this._fatherExtraData = 'father extra';
        this._childExtraData = 'child extra';
    }
}

const test: Child = new Child('something for the father');
test.setChildData('something for the kid');

let text: string = '';
text += `FATHER: ${test.fatherData()}\n`;
text += ` extra: ${test.fatherExtraData()}\n`;
text += `CHILD:  ${test.childData()}\n`;
text += ` extra: ${test.childExtraData()}\n`;
document.body.innerHTML = `<pre>${text}</pre>`;
```

From this I expect something like this:

```
FATHER: something for the father
 extra: father extra
CHILD:  something for the kid
 extra: child extra
```

But instead I get this:

```
FATHER: something for the father
 extra: father extra
CHILD:  something for the kid
 extra: null
```

In a way, I intuit the one calling the method `load()` is `Father` and not `Child` messing with the scope and not acting as expected.

Notes:

1. abstract or not it's the same problem.
2. generics or not it's also the same.

Answer (score 1):

Your Child class is equivalent to the following code, which should make it clear why you observe this behavior:

```
class Child extends Father<string> {
  protected _childData: string;
  protected _childExtraData: string;

  constructor(fatherData: string) {
    super(fatherData);

    console.log('in constructor: ' + this._childExtraData);

    this._childData = null;
    this._childExtraData = null;
  }

  public childData(): string {
    return this._childData;
  }
  public childExtraData(): string {
    return this._childExtraData;
  }
  public setChildData(data: string): void {
    this._childData = data;
  }

  protected load(): void {
    this._fatherExtraData = 'father extra';
    this._childExtraData = 'child extra';
  }
}
```

In short: the Child constructor resets the field to null after the super constructor has initialized it.

Calling an overridable method from a base cass constructor is a bad idea: the child method will be called on an object that has not been initialized yet by its constructor, leading to all kinds of subtle bugs, like the one you're seeing there. Avoid this bad practice.

Comment: Though, I still wonder, this is a technique I've using in other languages for a long time.
Once inherited, when a parent calls a method overwritten in a child, that method runs in the scope of the child.
Is this something that only happens in TypeScript?

Anyways, I thank you for the way you've rewritten the class, it'll make me think differently about how TypeScript inheritance works.

Comment: It's the same principle in Java too, for example. And it's also a bad practice there. It does run in the context of the child, but the child constructor has not complete yet, so fields that should never be null because they're initialized in the constructor are null when the method is called, for example. The usual invariants are broken when using this technique. An init method, or a static factory method, is preferrable in such a case.